# Java - print X^X^X squares

Tags: java, loops

I got a task to do, my task is to print X amount of squares of X^X. for example the correct output for input "3" is the following picture

Example here:
[image]

My code:

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
int base, k=0;
System.out.println("Enter a number do draw some squares");
base = s.nextInt();
int bb = base*base;

for (int t=0; t<=bb; t++) {
    if (t<bb) {
        for (int i=0; i<base; i++) {
            for (k=0; k<=base; k++) {
                if (k<base) 
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

When trying to use '2' as the base the output is:

```
** ** 
** ** 
** ** 
** **
```

My output:
[image]

How I can do the spaces between every 2 lines?

Sincerely,

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println();` after the `k` for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
int base, k=0;
System.out.println("Enter a number do draw some squares");
base = s.nextInt();
int bb = base*base;

for (int t=0; t<=bb; t++) {
    if (t<bb) {
        if(t%base == 0) {
           System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i=0; i<base; i++) {
            for (k=0; k<=base; k++) {
                if (k<base) 
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

https://ideone.com/MD8Kol

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the output when the loop counter is divisible by base i.e. when `the_loop_counter % base = 0`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number do draw some squares: ");
        int base = s.nextInt();
        int bb = base * base;

        for (int i = 1; i <= bb; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= bb; j++) {
                System.out.print(j % base == 0 ? "* " : "*");
            }
            System.out.println(i % base == 0 ? System.lineSeparator() : "");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a number do draw some squares: 3

*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 

*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 

*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 
*** *** ***
```

Comment: `"\n"` should be [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--), otherwise you would get `\n\r\n` at end of some lines on Windows, i.e. mixed bag of line separators.

Comment: Or simply `if (i % base == 0) System.out.println();`.

Comment: I think this code is cleaner than the code from the other answers, as it uses just two loops instead of three or for, and is more compact and better readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of modulo operator (`%`) to pick every n-th line.

Comment: @ppawel that's correct, I added an answer because I was doing it in ideone

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with 4 nested loops:

```java
static void printSquares(int n) {
    for (int boxRow = 0; boxRow < n; boxRow++) {
        for (int starRow = 0; starRow < n; starRow++) {
            for (int boxCol = 0; boxCol < n; boxCol++) {
                for (int starCol = 0; starCol < n; starCol++) {
                    System.out.print('*');
                }
                System.out.print(' ');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*Output for `printSquares(2)`*

```
** ** 
** ** 

** ** 
** **
```

*Output for `printSquares(3)`*

```
*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 

*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 

*** *** *** 
*** *** *** 
*** *** ***
```

Comment: Excellent solution, but where you got the input for "n"?
I think I still didn't learn that method

Comment: @Kapaznik Oh sorry, you haven't learned about methods yet? You will soon. The `n` is a method parameter, and would have the value the question code has in `base`. You can rename `n` to `base`, then drop the first and last lines shown here.

Comment: good to know, so when using this method you don't need to use "Scanner" to get the input?

Comment: @Kapaznik If you want to prompt the user, yeah you do. But there are other ways to come up with the number, e.g. you can hard-code it, like shown in this answer: `printSquares(2)` is a call to the method, setting `n = 2`.